# Makefile evaluation time of a variable's value

Tags: makefile

I have a small program to compile c sources and then link them, I define a function for that and then in the linking phase the program does not find the object files while I have checked and they exist.
The function is only able to link them when I run make for the second time.

```
define compile
$(foreach s,$(SRC),gcc s -o $(addprefix $(OBJECT_DIR)/, $(patsubt %.c.%.o,$(notdir $(s))));)
    gcc -shared -o sharedlib.so $(wildcard $(OBJECT_DIR)/*.o)
endef
all:
    $(call compile)
```

I have tried to echo the value of `$(OBJECT_DIR)` and it is empty when running make for the first time, it only get filled with the appropriate value in the second time I run make

Comment: What do you expect `$(gcc ...)` to do?

Comment: well sorry that was a typo

Comment: How many different directories are your source files in?

Comment: The sources are contained in 3 directories all in `SRC` variable, and the `OBJECT_DIR` was created during the process, I am afraid the `$(wildcard $(OBJECT-DIR)/*.o)` is evaluated at compilation time and not at run time that is why it is empty.

Comment: Yes, I know. There's more than one way to solve it; I think the best way is to eliminate the `foreach` entirely. I'll try to write up an answer in a few hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is radically different from your design, but I think it's the way to go:

```
OBJ := $(patsubst %.c, $(OBJECT_DIR)/%.o, $(notdir $(SRC)))

vpath %.c $(dir $(SRC))

sharedlib.so: $(OBJ)
    gcc -shared -o $@ $^

$(OBJ): $(OBJECT_DIR)/%.o: %.c
    gcc s -o $@ $<
```

Comment: I have put `$(patsubst %.c,%.o, $(addprefix $(OBJECT_DIR)/,$(filter %.c,$(notdir $(SRC)))))` instead of just filtering the object files from the `OBJECT_DIR` in the linking part. Thank you